# How to import figure from subfolder to tex file in another sub folder

Tags: import, includegraphics

I would need to know how to import figure from Figures subfolder to tex file in Chapters subfolder.

Project tree is following:

```
/Project/main.tex
/Project/Figures/picture.pdf
/Project/Chapters/chapter1.tex
```

I have tried to use either relative and absolute path to the picture.pdf but nothing works. I think the problem is I am trying to import the figure between subfolders (when I tried to import the figure from subfolder to the main.tex it works all right)

Thanks for help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `../Figures/picture.pdf` should work as well as `/Project/Figures/picture.pdf` (as long as `/Project` is a valid path)... Can you please be more specific on what fails? Any error message?

Comment: As far as I know the base directory of a project is that one the main tex file resides in. So using `./Figures/` as path for `\graphicspath` should do what you want from every folder within our project... The real problem is difficult to track down without a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your project in a folder named "Project" at any place of your OS.

Then inside it you could have:

`/Chapter1`

which contains its figures inside the subfolder

`/Chapter1/Figures`

Then:

`/Chapter2`

with its figures inside

`/Chapter2/Figures`.

To use it via `\graphicspath` command you have to place at the beggining of every `Chapter<number>.tex` the command:

`\graphicspath{{Chapter<number>/Figures/}}`

PS: This could be automated to be executed just inside \chapter command... if you are interested feel free to ask about this automation.

PS2: Change `<number>` with your real chapter's number of course.

Comment: I found the problem I tried to use the \graphicspath in chapter.tex file which I input in document part of the main.tex file so the command was not used in the preamble of file.

Comment: @MartinVit .. You should write this as a self placed answer and accept in a few days. A MWE could help you to find it earlier.